# Composer unable to find transaction function

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

**My Logic File is:**

```
function onIssuingBookFunction(bookIssue){

bookIssue.book_to_issue.issued_by = bookIssue.book_issuer;

return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sicsrblockchain.Book').then(function (assetRegistry) {

return assetRegistry.update(bookIssue.book_to_issue);

});

}
```

**When running a test, I am getting the following error:**

Error: `Could not find any functions to execute for transaction org.acme.sicsrblockchain.bookIssue#111bfb9f-17e5-4466-a215-50c60e072097`

Please help me regarding the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please answer your own question if this is resolved, so it is "closed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

annotations were missing.. moreover bookIssue.book_to_issue.issued_by = bookIssue.book_issuer; needed to be changed